# Maximum executable size on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone

Is there a maximum size of executables or executables + shared objects on the iPhone? I've been developing an app that has been crashing on startup or early in execution with SIGSYS. Removing code from the program has helped, though structuring data so the code is simply not executed does not.

This could be memory corruption, of some kind, however when I compiled with -Os rather than -O2 or -O3 the size of my executable goes down from 5.15MB to 3.60MB and the application runs perfectly. I also have a bunch of libraries I use, of course.

I'm wondering, is there a limit on the size of executable code on the iPhone? Or am I just 'getting lucky' and masking memory corruption when I use -Os?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a maximum size, there's no way you are hitting it with a 5.15 or 3.60 MB app file.  You have a different bug in your app.

You are getting lucky.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably just running out of memory. Are you getting memory warnings?

Comment: I'm not running out of memory. When I compile with -Os I can get far enough into my program to load many megabytes of data. I have run out of memory before, but only after loading much more than this.

Comment: In that case I'm going to have to agree with @marcc; your bug is elsewhere and you're getting lucky.

Answer (score 0):

There is a maximal executable size for delivery via the app store but the hardware itself imposes no unusual restrictions.

Your problem is most likely in one of your libraries. Which, based on your description of the complexity of your app, is not a helpful observation on my part.

Given the pattern with the compiler options, I'm going to take a wild, wild guess that you've got library that has a problem and the tighter compile causes that code to be excluded.

Under the heading of a longshot, you might also want to take a look at resources such as images as well. I've seen a couple of case in the past couple of years in which seemingly innocuous resources have trigger fatal errors when they loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have hit exactly the same problem. In some tens or hundreds of C++ kloc I never had any problems. Now I essentially copy&pasted a class and renamed two buttons and I get an access violation at startup.

None of the new code is ever executed, just linked in because I take the address of a function. The newly linked compilation unit does not rely on a single static symbol from the outside that could cause background code execution.

The debugger does not point to a useful location. My executable is at around 3.6 MB.